# Debugging Array Cakephp 2.x $this->request->data

Tags: debugging, cakephp-2.3

I am struggling trying to figure out how to debug an array in Cakephp 2.3. According to the documentation I am suppose to be using the Debugger class, but I do not see anything that debugs arrays. I am use to using die(debug()), var_dump, and pr() in older versions of Cake. Any input would be greatly appreciated here! Thank you!

Comment: debug($array) still works fine in 2.3 as long as you have Configure::write('debug', 2); in your core.php...

Comment: Sorry, should have said that, as stated here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html 'Output from this function is only shown if the core debug variable has been set to a value greater than 0' i.e a value of 1 or 2 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Ive got it figured out. I just debugged $this->data. I thought $this-data was deprecated in Cakephp 2.0. That is why I was trying to debug $this->request->data.